# JavaFX/WebView set element class attribute

Tags: java, webview, javafx

I am trying to set a div's class attribute as follows in a JavaFX WebView:

```
Element div = webView.getEngine().getDocument().createElement("div");
div.setAttribute("class", "myCssClass");
//append div to body...
```

However, setting the div's class attribute like this does not seem to have any effects.
Is there something I am missing? I also tried "className" as attribute name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found a (or the) solution:

```
HTMLElement div = (HTMLElement) webView.getEngine().getDocument().createElement("div");
div.setClassName("myCssClass");
```

Comment: Het Erdal. Do you know how I can get a classname of an webview loaded in javaFX app? Thanks

Comment: Assuming that you mean the class attribute of a DOM Node within the WebView instance, then just get that `DOM Node` by ID or in a similar manner, cast it to `org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLElement` (WebKit DOM impl is W3C compliant) and call `getClassName()` on it.